# Rotate and return the ArrayList<Integer> in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

here in below program i am defining **ArrayList** of size 7 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and and rotating right by 3 places but when i print the numbers1 list it gives me my expected answer **numbers: [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]** but when i return this ArrayList and then print it, it gives me this answer **numbers: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]** why is that please explain.

```
package QAIntvSprint;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RotateArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int k = sc.nextInt();

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    rotateArray(numbers, k);
    ArrayList<Integer> ans = rotateArray(numbers, k);
    for (Integer x : ans) {
      System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
  }

  static ArrayList<Integer> rotateArray(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      numbers.add(0, numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1));
      numbers.remove(numbers.size() - 1);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers1 = numbers;
    System.out.println("numbers: " + numbers1.toString());
    return numbers1;
  }
}
```

output

[image]

Comment: You didn't "return" it ..you rotated (`numbers`) twice! (What is the "purpose" of `numbers1` in `rotate` method?;)

Comment: What does `ans` (spectacular) ..in main method? (You could also refactor it to a `void` method and operate on `numbers` ;)

Comment: You think your method is working on your "original" arraylist `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, but instead your arraylist is modified each time you call rotateArray().

Comment: This has to do with Java pass by value, and if my understanding is correct, your method takes a copy of the object reference, follows it to the actual object, and modifies the values there. It does not take a copy of the arraylist passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your function **twice**:

```
rotateArray(numbers, k); // first
ArrayList<Integer> ans = rotateArray(numbers, k); // second
```

So the numbers are shifted by 6 instead of 3 positions

Besides, your function **does not create** a new copy of the array
You return a reference to the **same array**

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers1 = numbers; // copies a reference to an object, not the object itself
return numbers1; // returns the original link
```

So i suggest refactoring your code like this:

```
public class RotateArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        
        // the function will modify the ArrayList by reference, it will change
        rotateArray(numbers, k);
        for (Integer x : numbers) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
    }
    
    static void rotateArray(ArrayList<Integer> numbers, int k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            numbers.add(0, numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1));
            numbers.remove(numbers.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your function `rotateArray` changes your numbers ArrayList you give it as parameter. So basically it changes the List (numbers) in your main method. And because you call the method two times, the array gets rotated in sum 6 times (like you see in your final output)

If you don't want to change the ArrayList you give in as a parameter, you should do something like

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList(numbers);
```

as first in you rotateArray method and then  rotate this list.

Answer (score 0):

here
`ArrayList<Integer> ans = rotateArray(numbers, k);`
rotates
numbers, returned by the previous line

Delete
`rotateArray(numbers, k);`